# Code snippet to offer additional libraries based on tags

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

The code snippet comes with a preselection of popular JavaScript libraries but it could extend its offering based on tags.

For example in this case it could offer to load the Ramda library:

[image]

---

I also like the suggestion made in this post:
[Add CDN links for libraries in tags wikis, which can be options to add into stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330429/1244884)